# Can someone translate what these say?

Tags: translation

I bought a hooded shirt/short sleeve pullover from yesstyle. It looked cool but I also want to know what the front means and what the top text on the back means.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Japanese writes 公開 instead of 公开. But all other words may also be used in Japanese. 公平、公正、公开 is mainly used in Chinese government, means "just, fair, (and,) open". 裁判 means judgment / referee (in game) in Chinese. It also means judgment in Japanese but seems mostly used as judgement by court.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first image says "公平，公正，公开" on the hoodie, firstly notice the bit of Japanese at the bottom. Chances are that isn't meant to be read in Chinese. Either way, the main three terms translate roughly as "impartial", "equitable", and "public" respectively. I guess the hoodie has something to do with freedom of speech or something similar.

The other central term is "裁判" which I had to look up, translations include: judgment, to referee, umpire, judge, and referee. Referee is also listed at the top of the hoodie in English. Honestly I have no clue what this hoodie is on about.

<s>久夕ツフ</s> スタッフ Are the Japanese characters at the bottom but I haven't found a translation

Edit: In hindsight it's probably meant to be worn by a referee, eheh

Comment: Yeah the product is called "Hooded Chinese Character short sleeve", and there's just a bunch of gibberish in the text on the back side of the hoodie. It's a cool hoodie imo, but I guess the translations on everything are poorly done.

Comment: @MichaelNguyen In hindsight it's probably meant to be worn by a referee

Comment: It probably includes multiple languages to convey equality between ethnicities when judging as a referee.

Comment: It is "スタッフ", Read as _Sutaffu_, mean "staff". You seems write 3 characters wrong...

Comment: @tsh well I don't know a lick of Japanese so that's to be expected

Comment: @小奥利奥 I just done some google translating (by hand writing)